# Store reference to method to be called later with different parameters

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, wrapper

I need to be able to have ONE variable type store references to different methods, then call them later with different parameters, and have them return something. The methods will each have different parameter types and output types. I've tried delegates, actions and Func.

**Pseudo code example below**

```
  public void Open(String directory){
  File.Open(Directory);
  }
  public string ChangeVolume(int volume){
  //Code to change volume 
  //return the new volume
  }
public static void Main{
 MyVaribleType var1 = Open;
 myVaribleType var2 = ChangeVolume;
  var1("C:\Windows");
  Console.WriteLine(var2(100) );
}
```

How would I accomplish this with a single variable type?

Comment: you can't really do that.

Comment: You can't have a single "variable type" for two different types. `void` isn't `string`, and `String` isn't `int`. You can, however, change the signatures to be `object Method(object[] params)` to be as generic as possible, but I don't really recommend that.

Comment: Tell us what problem you're trying to solve.  Perhaps there's a better way to solve it than this.

Comment: It's an AI. When ever the AI sees a word, it has to go into its memory and search for the word, then execute the action/method associated with that word, but the action associated with that word may change(learning AI, or me manually changing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold references to the methods in collection of MethodInfo class provided by reflection APIs. To be able to call these methods you will also need to keep the references of the objects on which you want to call these methods. You can use reflection itself to invoke these methods. Reflection is slow so you can use this method only if you don't have high performance requirements.

Comment: This worked terrifically, but I dont yet know if speed will be an issue or not. Thanks....       Also is it good practice to post the new working code for others to see

Comment: Thanks. It's my first answer on stack overflow and I am using it on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it quite as you want to: the two methods have different signatures as @Mephy noted. You can do it using delegates, though:

```
public delegate FileStream OpenFileHandler(string filePath);
public delegate string ChangeVolumeHandler(FileStream stream, int volume);

class Program
{
    private static FileStream Open(string filePath)
    {
        return File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
    private static string ChangeVolume(FileStream stream, int volume)
    {
        return "Done! Honest!";
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenFileHandler ofh = Program.Open;
        ChangeVolumeHandler cvh = Program.ChangeVolume;
        FileStream stream = ofh("path");
        string xyzzy = cvh(stream, 100);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but I assume that this is a rather more complex requirement that you've shown, so fine.

Note that in addition to having to use two delegates, you aloso have to pass each the items it needs to work on and that it creates (e.g. the FileStream object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.ChangeVolume = new Func<int, string>(ChangeVolume);
```

and then call it thusly:

```
var result = d.ChangeVolume(volume);  //ChangeVolume is type-checked at runtime.
```

or simply write the logic into the new dynamic property directly:

```
d.ChangeVolume = new Func<int, string>(x => (x * x).ToString()); // or whatever
```